# How to print ONCE if there are multiple correct answers? (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, indexing, printing, matlab-figure

So I have arr = randi([0,20],20,1). I want to show: If there are numbers less than 5, fprintf('Yes\n') only once. Im using a for  loop (for i = 1 : length(arr)) and indexing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `break` statement upon finding the first value under 5 and printing the `Yes` statement.

### Using a `break` Statement:

```
arr = randi([0,20],20,1);

for i = 1: length(arr)
    if arr(i) < 5
    fprintf("Yes\n");
    break;
    end
end
```

### Extension:

### By Using `any()` Function:

Alternatively, if you'd like to concise it down without the need for a for-loop the `any()` function can be used to determine if any values within the array meet a condition in this case `arr < 5`.

```
arr = randi([0,20],20,1);

if(any(arr < 5))
    fprintf("Yes\n");

end
```

### By Using a While Loop:

```
Check = 0;
arr = randi([0,20],20,1);

i = 1;
while (Check == 0 && i < length(arr))    
if arr(i) < 5
    fprintf("Yes\n");
    Check = 1;
end

i = i + 1;
end
```

Comment: is there a way not to use break?

Answer (score 1):

As your description, maybe you need `if` statement within `for` loop like below

```
for i = 1:length(arr)
  if arr(i) < 5
    fprintf('Yes\n');
    break
  end
end
```

---

If you want to print `Yes` once, you can try

```
if any(arr < 5)
  fprintf('Yes\n')
endif
```

---

If you don't want to use `break`, the code below might be an option

```
for i = 1:min(find(arr <5))
  if (arr(i) < 5)
    fprintf('Yes\n');
  end
end
```

Comment: is there a way not to use break?